# Manipulating GridView TemplateFields Depending on DataTable Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

### Background

This is the scenario:
I have a `GridView` with five columns

1. an `asp:CommandField` set to `readonly`
2. an `asp:BoundField` set to `readonly`
3. another `asp:BoundField` set to `readonly`
4. another `asp:BoundField` set to `readonly`
5. and an `asp:TemplateField` with the following under this field.

   - `EditItemTemplate`

     - `asp:TextBox`

For simplicity we'll assume the `DataTable` that the `GridView` is bound to has only two rows.

### Goal

What I'd like to achieve is once the page has been loaded and the data table bound to the grid view I want the first row of the grid view to be in edit mode based on the value of row one, cell five in the data table. And by edit mode I mean the `TextBox` in the `TemplateField` to be displayed and the Update button in the `CommandField` column to be displayed as well.
Where as row two of the grid view is in normal mode based on the value of row two, cell five in the data table and at the same time the `CommandField` column displays the update link then making the `TextBox` editable on the second row of the grid view.

The positions of the cell values is indiscriminate. I know how to specify which cell to look at to determine the state of the row, I just don't know how to set the row state to edit, and the `TextBox` viewable on data source binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either on DataBound event or RowDataBound event of the Grid:

1) Grid_DataBound:

```
protected void grid1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int editIndex = -1;
        // find the row index which is editable


        grid1.EditIndex = editIndex;
        // Set EditIndex = -1 to set the row to normal mode
    }
```

2) RowDataBound

```
protected void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            bool isEdit = false;
            // check for the condition to determine the state of the row

            if (isEdit)
            {
                e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this help.